# Push Notifications stopped working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using IBM MobileFirst 6.3, with Apple, Android, Blackberry and Windows Environments.

I have enabled Push Notifications for Apple, Android and Windows environment. I mistakenly uploaded application with sandbox certificate on my production server. On noticing the mistake, I removed the version with Sandbox certificate and uploaded the production certificate version properly and restarted the Websphere Liberty server.

After the restart, push notification is NOT WORKING for any platform.

Earlier I got APNS SSL connection error in my logs, but now I can not see any Push related error in my logs, I enabled trace on com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.*=all, and still got nothing back.

The only error I get is of could not piggyback ... , which I believe even IBM is suggesting to suppress. I have attached the finest level trace [here](http://pastebin.com/QYZKDtFr)

I have checked through Wireshark, and server receives request on HTTP GET method and replies with status 200. But what happens after that is a mystery.

P.S. The push notification worked once while the SandBox certificate version was enabled, but didn't work after the restart at all.

Comment: Trace does not show any indication of push messages being dispatched. How are you invoking the adapter to send notifications.

Comment: @VivinK yes that's what been bugging me a lot. I used the standard push calls as per documentation, the push notifications were working fine till yesterday, however after the restart of the Websphere Server, they stopped working.

You can see the submitNotification function code [here](http://pastebin.com/HHesS19u)

Comment: I am invoking adapter via this call

'https://URL/CONTEXT/invoke?adapter=PushAdapter&procedure=submitNotification&parameters=%5B%27username%27%2C%27Message%27%5D'

Comment: I think the adapter invocation itself fails and the flow does not get push notification dispatch

Comment: What is the exact MobileFirst server version, you are using

Comment: I am using 6.3.0.00.20150404-1503 on server, but the application WAR was built using 6.3.0.00.20150521-2300

Comment: but when I invoke the adapter via browser, I receive below response:

'/*-secure-
{"result":"Notification sent to user :: ldap.user","isSuccessful":true}*/'

Comment: Do you see any messages in the logs, that says didnot send push , because application is disabled?

Comment: nope not a single such message, I have disabled older versions of the application, do you think that could be a problem??

Comment: I have checked via wireshark, the server receives http packet with adapter invoke, and replies back with status 200.

Comment: That means server is not processing the request. This requires more analysis. If you are customer or business partner can you open a PMR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98106/discussion-between-vivin-k-and-eshaa).

Answer (score 0):

@eshaa when you use to change in certificate related settings in client side code you need to take new build i means new .wlapp files to be upload to the server then it will be effect whatever changes you done.